# DC Motor Rotate Direction

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor

What are possible solutions for changing DC motor rotate direction controlled by microcontroller? I know that H-bridge is one possible solution, but i want to use 2 pins for control only.

Comment: What power motor? Do you want two directions AND stop or always rotating? Do you want speed control? | 1 pin can easily control an H bridge in two directions with a few extra parts. And 1 pin can do full 2 direction speed control AND stop if desperate enough. ( Stop = hi-Z. Fwd = eg hi-Z to drive high PWM. Reverse = hi-Z to low PWM.). | Or with suitable decode PWM can be decoded to eg STOP at 50:50, controlled speed fwd at > 50:50, controlled speed reverse at < 50:50).

Comment: 12v DC Motor, I want start stop and direction change control, but only with two pins.

Comment: So you do not want speed control?

Comment: No, I just need what I wrote

Comment: H Bridge: Drive top left and bottom right with 1 pin to operate motor say clockwise. Drive top right and bottom left to drive motor anticlockwise. || As Spehro says - One SPDT relay will do one direction as above. And a second will do the other. OR a single DPDT relay will allow one pint to select rotation eg low = CW. high = ACW or whatever. And second pin is on-off. | OR with one pin: Hi-z pull to 1/2 supply = off. Lo = eg CW, high= CCW. ONE pin.

Comment: re "No, I just need what I wrote" -> The instances where that is true are non zero but small. Where the question is not exceedingly well done to start and the text amount in response to questions is << the text amount in the questions the odds of it being so are exceedingly small. One ALMOST always finds that when answers are near monosyllabic and/or verging on lippy that it's not because Yoda is answering :-)

Comment: Re "12v DC Motor, I want start stop and direction change control, but only with two pins. –  Master Yoda 6 hours" see
"answered 20 hours ago Spehro Pefhany " for "all you want".

Comment: Sorry for fast and short answer, I just need on/off and rotation direction change options :)

Comment: So presumably the answer from Spehro and the various comments above provide all you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two half bridges or two SPDT relays will allow you to control on/off and  direction with two pins.